# Lemma 8.23 (Gilbarg-Trudinger)

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, holder-spaces

My doubt is in a step of the following lemma

> **Lemma** Let w be a non-decreasing function on an interval (0, Ro] satisfying,
> for all $R \le R_0$, the inequality
> \begin{equation}
> w(\tau R) \le \gamma w(R) + \sigma(R) 
> \end{equation}
> where $\sigma$ is also non-decreasing and $0 < \gamma, \tau< 1$. Then, for any $ \mu \in (0, 1)$ and $R \le R_0$,
> we have
> \begin{equation}
> w(R) \le C \left(\left(\frac{R}{R_0} \right)^\alpha w(R_0) + \sigma (R^\mu R^{1-\mu}) \right)
> .\end{equation}
> where $c= C( \gamma, \tau)$ and $\alpha = \alpha(\gamma, \tau ,\mu)$ are positive constants.

The doubt that I have is in the following step of the short proof of the lemma.  For any $ R \le R_1, m$ was chosen so that
$$
\tau^m R_1 \le R \le \tau^{m-1} R_1
$$
How can I see that
$$
\gamma^{m-1} \le \frac{1}{\gamma} \left (\frac{R}{R_1} \right )^{\log \gamma /\log \tau}?
$$
**My thoughts**
$$ 
\gamma^{m-1} = \frac{1}{\gamma} \gamma^m
$$
and
$$ \tau^m < R/R_1$$
It follows that (as $ \gamma <1$)
$$
m> \log_\tau \left (R/R_1\right )
$$

Comment: Please adjust the question. There are missing parts and a lot of typos.

Comment: I believe that I have made the changes now.

Comment: There is still something wrong with the first inequality. I don't believe that in Trudinger there is the same term on the lhs and the rhs. Also you don't specify what is $\gamma$. It is hard to help someone which does not put effort in writing a proper question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed very simple: You want

$$\gamma^{m} \le \left (\frac{R}{R_1} \right )^{\log \gamma /\log \tau}, $$

taking $\log$, this is equivalent to

\begin{align} 
m \log \gamma &\le \frac{\log \gamma}{\log \tau} \log\left (\frac{R}{R_1} \right )\\
\Leftrightarrow m \log \tau &\le \log\frac{R}{R_1}  \qquad \qquad \ \ \left( \text{note }\frac{\log \gamma}{\log \tau}>0\right)\\
\Leftrightarrow \tau ^m &\le \frac{R}{R_1}
\end{align}

which is $\tau^m R_1\le R$.